# disable button for a period of time

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, timing

I created an **Animation** on my Windows Phone 8 app

but i don't know how to make a button **Disabled** or **Disappear** when the Animation is **executing**

and when it finishes , the button will be **Enabled** or **Visible** again

So where should i add a code that makes the **Button disabled** ?

My animation code :

```
 //h1 is the animation picture 
  private void h2_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {


            Duration Time_duration2 = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            Storyboard MyStory2 = new Storyboard();

            MyStory2.Duration = Time_duration2;

            DoubleAnimation My_Double2 = new DoubleAnimation();

            My_Double2.Duration = Time_duration2;

            MyStory2.Children.Add(My_Double2);

            RotateTransform MyTransform2 = new RotateTransform();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(My_Double2, MyTransform2);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(My_Double2, new PropertyPath("Angle"));

            My_Double2.To = 180;

            h2.RenderTransform = MyTransform2;

            h2.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            MyStory2.Begin();

        }
```

**UPDATE**  : I added `pass.IsEnabled = false;` after `MyStory2.Begin();`

so now when i press at the **Animation** the **Button** is **Disabled** , but when it **Finishes** the button should be back to **Enabled** , so where do i put `pass.IsEnabled = true;`  ?

Comment: @pasty it doesn't work , nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so now when i press at the Animation the Button is Disabled , but when it Finishes the button should be back to Enabled , so where do i put pass.IsEnabled = true; ?

The Storyboard has a [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. Just subscribe to it, and set the value of `IsEnabled` when the event is raised.